# ruby how to use "||" (or-equals) operator in parentheses after "==" to match multiple expressions, i.e. x == (5 || 6)

Tags: ruby, equality, parentheses, or-operator

I'm trying to get the `==` operator to match two possible values like so.

```
def demo(x)
  puts "foo!" if x == (5 || 7)
end

demo(5)
#=> "foo!"
demo(7)
#=> nil
```

So this doesn't work, but is there a way to match multiple values at the end of a `==` operator in ruby? I think I've seen it done before, so that's why I tried it, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
def demo(x)
  puts "foo!" if x == 5 || x == 7
end
```

`x == (5 || 7)` won't work because `5 || 7` is `5`, so it's the same as `x == 5`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options

```
... if x == 5 || x == 7
... if [5, 7].include?(x)
... if x.in?(5, 7) # if in rails
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: No, it's not possible:
http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html

> Comparison Operators
>
> The Ruby syntax defines the comparison operators ==, ===, <=>, <, <=, >, >=, =~, and the standard methods eql? and equal? (see Table 7.1). **All of these operators are implemented as methods.** Although the operators have intuitive meaning, it is up to the classes that implement them to produce meaningful comparison semantics. The library reference describes the comparison semantics for the built-in classes. The module Comparable provides support for implementing the operators ==, <, <=, >, >=, and the method between? in terms of <=>. The operator === is used in case expressions, described in the section “Case Expressions”.

So it's a method with only one argument. and `(x||y)` will always return x unless, x is false.

Comment: longer (full) version of the second component Yu Hao's answer, thanks Jan

Comment: got it, `(1||2) == 1# => true`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit of an abuse of `case`, but it can make it easy to read, and write, this sort of code:

```
def demo(x)
  case x
  when 5, 7
    puts "foo!"
  end
end
```

Normally we'd have more `when` clauses. The nice thing about this is, it's easy to add more values that `x` needs to match:

```
def demo(x)
  case x
  when 5, 7, 9..11
    puts "foo!"
  end
end

[5, 7, 10].each do |i|
  demo(i)
end
```

Running that results in:

```
foo!
foo!
foo!
```

Trying to do the same with `if` results in visual noise that can obscure the intent of the logic, especially when more tests are added:

```
case x
when 5, 7, 9..11, 14, 15, 20..30
  puts "foo!"
end
```

Versus:

```
puts 'foo!' if (x == 5 || x == 7 || x == 14 || x == 15 || 9..11 === x || 20..30 === x)
```

Or:

```
puts 'foo!' if (
  x == 5  ||
  x == 7  ||
  x == 14 ||
  x == 15 ||
  9..11  === x ||
  20..30 === x
)
```

Comment: huh this is different. nice one I'll be sure to use that. What I'm really doing in my proto-app/code today is prompting responses from the user at the command line and handling those responses, so the case method is probably the most "ruby-like" (i.e. prose-like, readable) of these answers. Directly using the low level conditional methods is more of a "C-style" approach perhaps

Comment: Well, C supports `switch` and `case` which is akin to Ruby's `case` and `when` respectively, so it can be cleaned up nicely. Now Perl... that's a different matter. :-)